# Stacking word bouncer

Tags: crosswords

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7062)</sup>

[image]

blue:
Am I (3<) a singer in a temple (3,5v) or in a a sun-starved (5^) metric conflict area (3,5>)?
red:
A disfiguring motherly animal(2,3,4v) with a not discrete behind (4,6<) has a flirty drink(3,5>) with an all-right animal (2,5^).
yellow:
Wearable fish (3,4^) are more normal (4,5>) than coin kissers at Chinese distance(2,3,4<) getting a next life (2,5v)
green:
You cannot win (5<) an already finished test (2,4v) with low prices (5>) or your fundamental qualities(6^).

Rules:
1/ The clues refer to words of with the length and direction from one of the colored cells is given. e.g. "a singer in a temple" contains the hints for two words, which both can be read downward starting directly below the blue tile. The 3 letter word thus coincides with the first three letters of the 5 letter word.
2/ The grey diagonal lines change the direction of the words using the cell 90 degrees (as if they were mirrors).
3/ It does not matter what is behind a word. The longest word will always overlap with the longest word from the other side. eg the last 2 letters of green-up and green-right will overlap.

Note: I hope you like the concept. This is my first 'crossword' so some descriptions may be weird, vague or refer to obscure words. Still I think there are enough clues that are easy enough. Constructive criticism is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

blue:
Am I (3<) a singer in a temple (3,5v) or in a a sun-starved (5^) metric conflict area (3,5>)?

> EGO / ALT ALTAR / UMBRA / ARE ARENA

red:
A disfiguring motherly animal(2,3,4v) with a not discrete behind (4,6<) has a flirty drink(3,5>) with an all-right animal (2,6^).

> MA MAR MARA / ANAL ANALOG / TEA TEASE / OK OKAPI

yellow:
Wearable fish (3,4^) are more normal (4,5>) than coin kissers at Chinese distance(2,3,4<) getting a next life (2,5v)

> GAR GARB / SANE SANER / LI LIP LIPA / KA KARMA

green:
You cannot win (5<) an already finished test (2,4v) with low prizes (5>) or your fundamental qualities(6^).

> LOSER / EX EXAM / SALES / NATURE